# Does In XQuery 1.0 exist a function that check if a value in a list is present in another one?

Tags: xml, xquery

Having two different list in XQuery

```
$list1:
A
B
C
D
```

and

```
$list2
A
D
```

Is there a function that does: create $list3 with all element of $list2 not present in $list1?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your values are atomic, you can exploit the existential semantics of `=`:

```
let $list1 := ('A', 'B', 'C', 'D')
let $list2 := ('A', 'D', 'E', 'F')
let $list3 := $list2[not(. = $list1)]
return $list3
```

Result: `'E', 'F'`

If you want to compare XML nodes by *node identity*, you can use the `except` keyword instead:

```
let $nodes := (<A/>, <B/>, <C/>, <D/>, <E/>, <F/>)
let $list1 := ($nodes[1], $nodes[2], $nodes[3], $nodes[4])
let $list2 := ($nodes[1], $nodes[4], $nodes[5], $nodes[6])
let $list3 := $list2 except $list1
return $list3
```

Result: `<E/>, <F/>`